# Type Error: XMLHttp is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I have tried with this code in JavaScript as follows:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest");

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://www.codecademy.com/",true);
xhr.send();

console.log(xhr.status);
console.log(xhr.statusText);
```

When I run this code using node.js at Command Prompt "node ***.js", an error message comes out saying that 'TypeError: XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor'. I appreciate for any help for why this error. Thanks.

Comment: It's got to be because the first line is failing.

Comment: `node.js` hasn't direct Ajax- API's. You must use Third-Party modules or the `net` component from `node.js`

Answer (score 11):

The first line should be:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
```

See the **[documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest)**.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to load the module as [smlhttprequest](https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest) and [demo](https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest/blob/master/example/demo.js)

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, definitely helpful.